# Check if string is part of object variables

Tags: python-3.x, object

I want to pass a string to a method/class function which resolves the correct attribute to modify. I'm pretty sure i've done this before, but I seem to have forgotten how to.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word = B.getWord()
        self.phrase = "Some default string"

    def set_dynamically(self, attribute, value):
        self[attribute] = value
```

This would let me do something like `A.set_dynamically('word', C.getWord())`

I've tried searching for a question and answer for this but I'm having a hard time defining what this is called, so I didn't really find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python objects have a built-in method called `__setattr__(self, name, value)` that does this. You can invoke this method by calling `setattr()` with an object as the argument:

```
A = A()
setattr(A, 'word', C.getWord())
```

There's no reason to do this when you could just do something like `A.word = C.getWord()` (which, in fact, resolves down to calling `__setattr__()` the same way as the built-in `setattr()` function does), but if the property you're setting is named dynamically, then this is how you get around that limitation.

If you want to customize the behavior of how your class acts when you try to call `setattr()` on it (or when you try to set an attribute normally), you can override the `__setattr__(self, name, value)` method in much the same way as you're overriding `__init__()`. Be careful if you do this, because it's really easy to accidentally produce an infinite recursion error - to avoid this you can use `object.__setattr__(self, name_value)` inside your overridden `__setattr__(self, name, value)`.

Comment: This is what i was after. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my own solution as well. I created a mapping object;

```
def _mapper(self, attr, object):

    m = { "funcA" : object.funcA,
          "funcB" : object.funcB,
           ...    : ...,
        }
    return m.get(attr)


def call_specific_func_(self, attr):

    --do stuff--
    for a in some-list:
        attr = a.get_attr() 
        retvals = self._mapper(attr, a)
        -- etc --
```